# Active handles of the server keeps on increasing and then stalls the server

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I have written a simple node API whose sole purpose is just to notify the user that the internet is alive. I am hitting this API after every 3 seconds and it works fine till the active handles are around 4000 or less but after then my server stops responding till the time I restart the server. I am running this server through pm2. I have attached a link to the image of my server when I type "pm2 monit".

```
   const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
        res.send({status:200, message:'request received'});
        return; // I assume res.send ends the request 
    });

    app.listen(5005, () => {
      console.log('Listening on port 5005');
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Missing image that you said you attached? You could just copy paste the text. However, this could be a very broad reason. Depends on how the pm2 is setup, the limitations of your machine (if this is ran locally), etc.

Comment: It could be server resources are getting exhausted since node.js is single threaded, It utilizes the CPU to its potential and that is where you might will need to stack up your infra. Also, I don't see link to the image of pm2 monit ?

Comment: The active handles just keep on increasing somehow and some of the HTTP connections are not closed to some clients once the request is served.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ThTr.png image link

Comment: @shiva2492 I don't see CPU utilization is reaching max limit

Comment: @MadaManu Here is the link http://i.stack.imgur.com/8ThTr.png

Comment: Could it be the amount of connections opened at the same time? I see 1162 being reported on that screenshot. Which would mean you'd want to use res.end() to close connection too after it sent the message.

Comment: @MadaManu Yes, that might be the reason.But I would like to close the connection once request response has been served

Comment: Yes, so try out: `res.send({status:200, message:'request received'}).end()` and re-run the test. Capture the same as you did already and also see if there's any improvement...

Comment: @MadaManu As far as I know res.send() also calls end() internally

Comment: @ShantanuMadane check this link https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2719 i hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Shantanu, For this purpose I think using `express` is an overkill. You can try with the native [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module and can try for the same. Please find below the code for a simple ping-pong based server.

```
const http = require("http");

http.createServer((request, response) => {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    response.write(JSON.stringify({ status: 200, message: "pong" }));
    response.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Also I think `pm2` clustering might cause a problem with this. Native Clustering can be an alternative to `pm2` for this use case.

Try the above code with `pm2` if the problem persists then try using native clustering using [`cluster`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module.

Below is the load test for the same using siege. The Code seems to perform well in my system.

[image: Siege Report http://localhost:8692/]

Comment: Can I see count of active handles in seige?

Comment: @Agnibha- How can I see active handles using seige?